# get signatureValue from getDataToSign method in DSS

Tags: rest, digital-signature, electronic-signature

I use `SD-DSS` open source solution to sign a document digitally. I checked [dss-documentation](https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/doc/dss-documentation.html#_get_data_to_sign) page, but not sure, how to get `signatureValue`, which is in sample request. As I interpret, I has to use output of `getDataToSign`, the digest as `signatureValue`, but there is mismatch between these values in sample `REST` project.

Output of `getDataToSign` is:

```
{{

{ "bytes" : "MYIBETAYBgkqhkiG9w0BCQMxCwYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMBwGCSqGSIb3DQEJBTEPFw0xODAzMjYwODEyMDlaMC0GCSqGSIb3DQEJNDEgMB4wDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQChDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwLwYJKoZIhvcNAQkEMSIEIBhfjbMicf4l9WGm/JOLLiZDBuwwTtpRgAfRdkgmOBlpMHcGCyqGSIb3DQEJEAIvMWgwZjBkMGIEIALz68oBYydCU7yAnSdJjdQbsDFtfmsGaWARXeFVWJ2cMD4wNKQyMDAxGzAZBgNVBAMMElJvb3RTZWxmU2lnbmVkRmFrZTERMA8GA1UECgwIRFNTLXRlc3QCBi7WFNe7Vw==" }
}}
```

Value in `signDocument` request:

```
{{ "signatureValue" : { "algorithm" : "RSA_SHA256", "value" : "AQIDBA==" },}}
```

UPDATE:

I use these requests:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<ns2:getDataToSign xmlns:ns2="http://signature.dss.esig.europa.eu/">
<dataToSignDTO>
<parameters>
<BLevelParams>
<trustAnchorBPPolicy>true</trustAnchorBPPolicy>
<signingDate>2019-01-01T01:01:01.464Z</signingDate>
</BLevelParams>
<digestAlgorithm>SHA256</digestAlgorithm>
<encryptionAlgorithm>RSA</encryptionAlgorithm>
<signatureLevel>PAdES_BASELINE_B</signatureLevel>
<signaturePackaging>ENVELOPED</signaturePackaging>
<signingCertificate>
<encodedCertificate>${#cert}</encodedCertificate>
</signingCertificate>
</parameters>
<toSignDocument>
<bytes><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="ref1"/></bytes>
</toSignDocument>
</dataToSignDTO>
</ns2:getDataToSign>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<ns2:signDocument xmlns:ns2="http://signature.dss.esig.europa.eu/">
<signDocumentDTO>
<parameters>
<BLevelParams>
<trustAnchorBPPolicy>true</trustAnchorBPPolicy>
<signingDate>2019-01-01T01:01:01.464Z</signingDate>
</BLevelParams>
<digestAlgorithm>SHA256</digestAlgorithm>
<signatureLevel>PAdES_BASELINE_B</signatureLevel>
<signaturePackaging>ENVELOPED</signaturePackaging>
<signingCertificate>
<encodedCertificate>${#cert}</encodedCertificate>
</signingCertificate>
</parameters>
<signatureValue>
<algorithm>RSA_SHA256</algorithm>
<value>${#datatosign}</value>
</signatureValue>
<toSignDocument>
<bytes><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="ref1"/></bytes>
<name>dsstest</name>
</toSignDocument>
</signDocumentDTO>
</ns2:signDocument>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Code to generate `signatureValue`:

```
try (Pkcs12SignatureToken token = new Pkcs12SignatureToken("src/main/resources/user_a_rsa.p12", new PasswordProtection("password".toCharArray()))) {

        List<DSSPrivateKeyEntry> keys = token.getKeys();
        for (DSSPrivateKeyEntry entry : keys) {
                System.out.println(entry.getCertificate().getCertificate());
        }

        ToBeSigned toBeSigned = new ToBeSigned("Hello world".getBytes());
        SignatureValue signatureValue = token.sign(toBeSigned, DigestAlgorithm.SHA256, keys.get(0));

        System.out.println("Signature value : " + Utils.toBase64(signatureValue.getValue()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSS is providing to you in `getDataToSign` the digest to be signed with the private key corresponding with the certificate you sent.

You have to digitally sign that value using the specified algorithm and send the result to `signDocument`. In your case RSA PKCS#1 with SHA256

Pseudocode

```
var digestToSign = getDataToSign(document, params)
var signatureValue = PKCS#1_v1.5(privateKey, digestToSign, SHA256)
var finalDocument = signDocument(signatureValue)
```

After this, DSS will build the final signed document.

Comment: I just executed Pkcs12SignatureTokenTest.java class (https://github.com/esig/dss/tree/master/dss-token/src/main/java/eu/europa/esig/dss/token) testPkcs12() method with my p12 file and getDataToSign method base64 encoded output. I got that output, so algorithm is the same as in signDocument request: `11:09:41.795 [main] INFO eu.europa.esig.dss.token.AbstractSignatureTokenConnection - Signature algorithm : SHA256withRSA` I used this signValue, but signed PDF is still invalid.

Comment: It could be an encoding problem, that you are signing with a private key that does not correspond to the public key, or that the parameters you send to getDataToSign and signDocument are not equivalent. Without seeing the code it is difficult to say. I suggest you edit the question with the relevant code

Comment: I edited question. testPkcs12() method isn't modified by me, just changed parameter  values, p12 file and value of toBeSigned variable.

Comment: Probably the error is in the processing of the SOAP parameters: when obtaining the digest to sign or when sending the signature made. In the values you show, the text `AQIDBA==` is incorrect and does not correspond to a PCKS1 signature. Review the encoding/decoding section of your code, or post the code here and I will try to take a look

Comment: That value is from documentation, from a sample request. I edited question and added Java code.

Comment: The code you have included signs the text "HelloWord", not a PDF. The signing of a plain text and a PDF requires different parameters. This code does not correspond to the SOAP messages exchanged. Is that the code you're really using or have you pasted a code from the documentation?

Comment: I pasted output of my first SOAP request in base64 encoded form in this: new ToBeSigned(<base64encodedtext>);

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. 1) you generate a SOAP request in some way 2) send it to the DSS server and copy the response manually 3) paste the base64 value in the signature code example 4) with the result you generate a new SOAP to send to DSS. The steps are correct but the execution seems not to be.

Comment: Manual processes do not usually end well. Without code and without seeing the detail of all the values that you send in each step, I do not think I can help you. As I said before, probably the problem is the encoding/decoding between base64 and binary values

Comment: Thanks, problem was base64 encoding process in signatureValue generator code.